# Bootstrap: append/prepend using

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm develope some project with Bootstrap, and here some others css, and somewhere it brakes bootstrap add-on(append/perpend). So, i can't solve this problem. Can you help me, please. 
I found that some fix can help me:

```
.input-prepend .add-on {
margin-right: -1px;
position:relative;
bottom:2px; 
}
```

but it isn't helps.

part of the html-code

```
<div class="form-string clearfix">
    <dl>
        <div class="span2">
            <dt>Phone:<span style="color:#ff0000">*</span></dt>
            <dd>
                <div class="input-prepend input-append">
                <span class="add-on" >+7</span><input type="text" maxlength="10" id="phone">
                <span class="add-on "><input id="alertphone" type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="addonCheckbox"></span> 
                </div>
            </dd>
        </div>
        <div class="span2" style="position:relative; left:-2%">
            <dt>&nbsp;</dt>
            <dd>
                Send SMS
            </dd>   
        </div>
    </dl>
</div>
```

[add-on problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iOdf.png)

Comment: if i understand you right - input and append/prepend displayed not in line. You can see sreenshot at the end of the post.

Comment: Then sorry, I can't help you as that link is block here. Describe your problem then I can try.. :)

Comment: Well, i will try) So, add-ons (append\prepend) are placed on different  lines. It should be - [prepend][input][append]. But it dislayed: [prepend]\n[input]\n[append]

Comment: You are missing the class `input-prepend` in the markup

Comment: I missed it only in this post. It has in real

Comment: I tried making a [fiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/MgcDU/6390/) but couldn't reproduce the issue with your code. I guess the cause for your issue is `span2` gives a width of 140px while the `input[type="text"]` has a width of `206px`, which makes it jump on the next line. Try giving `input` a width of around 100px for test.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try it:**

```
<div class="form-string clearfix">
<dl>
    <div class="span2">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="email">Phone:<span style="color:#ff0000">*</span></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend input-append">
                    <span class="add-on" >+7</span>
                    <input type="text" maxlength="10" id="phone">
                    <span class="add-on "><input id="alertphone" type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="addonCheckbox"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span2" style="position:relative; left:-2%">
        <dt>&nbsp;</dt>
        <dd>
            Send SMS
        </dd>   
    </div>
</dl>
```

Are you forget, **input-prepend** and **input-append** ?

Also in my opinion, used only **div** tags.

Important, examine for Ver. 3+ new class tags: http://goo.gl/t6GnwL

Comment: Well, i missed it only in this post) In real - i have it) Also, using only **div** not helps

Comment: My Organized in the same codes with my trial board Bootstrap. Screen http://goo.gl/xbnuwG